# How does Docker handle a system shutdown?

Tags: linux, docker

*This exact question has been asked before [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48501452) and [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/3piap1/what_does_happen_to_my_container_if_the_host_is/). However, the actual question is never answered.*

I have our Atlassian services running inside docker containers. However, I am wondering what happens when I issue a `shutdown` command to **the host**. Does it try to gracefully shutdown the containers, or does it try to immediately kill them? Somehow I seem to be unable of finding actual resources on this, maybe as I am rather new to docker.

Imagine the following:

1. I have running containers
2. I issue the `shutdown` command to turn off **the host** *without* explicitly issuing `docker stop`

What does docker do in such a scenario? Can I safely issue the `shutdown` command, and expect my containers to be gracefully shut down before anything else?

*In my case I use an Ubuntu Server 19.04 instance if that matters, but the question is aimed at a more general scenario / covering the main distros.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your containers should receive a SIGTERM like all other processes in the system.

The catch is that what gets the SIGTERM is the main process in the container (the one started by ENTRYPOINT). If the container runs a script to startup a binary, it is important to `exec` the binary so that it becomes the container process, otherwise the SIGTERM is received by the shell interpreter which usually won't forward it to the child.

AFAIK `docker stop` first tries a SIGTERM on the container and expects it to exit within 10 seconds, if not it send a SIGKILL. So if your containers stops quickly on `docker stop` you should be fine.

Comment: That's a good catch. I'll have to check my dockerfiles for that. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There theoretical approach (by @xenoid), and practical one.

Issue the server shutdown, and observe what happens.

1. **The console.** Although the network could be immediately cut, the shutdown sequence may still take quite some time. Observe from the console (some hosting providers provide virtual console) how it goes - how long does the shutdown sequence actually take, and what happens meanwhile?
2. **The logs.** From what I have seen, database container is often the worry. Will it be killed, or gracefully terminated? The truth is in the logs. Observe them carefully. If you boot up the system and see these logs with the shutdown timestamps, you are doing pretty good:

.

```
2023-08-11 14:43:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[...]
2023-08-11 14:43:21 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete
```

3. **Shutdown timing configuration.** You may also investigate further how to change reboot timing parameters. See `man systemd-system.conf` and check this paragraph: `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=, DefaultTimeoutStopSec=, DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=, DefaultRestartSec=`. The default is 90 seconds.